# Text over-laping CSS Image

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website using HTML5, and CSS3. I've been creating a Image with pure CSS and having some trouble when I put two CSS images together and one of them has a few lines of text.

I'll get straight to the point now - I've created a square Image and divided them together. I've placed some text in one of them using:

```
<p></p>
```

Here's the source of the the CSS Image with the text:

```
#right {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 900px;
position:absolute;
border-width:1px;
display: block;
border-style:solid;
margin-left: auto;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-size: 85%;
margin-right; auto;
color: #000000;
border-right-color:white;
border-color:grey;border-style:solid;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
top:300px;
width: 300px;
left:102px;
```

Here's the second CSS Image source:

```
#middle { 
background-color: #FFFFFF;
height: 900px;
position:absolute;
color: #000000;
display: block;
margin-left:auto;
border-right-color:white;
border-width:1px;
text-align:center;
margin-right; auto;
border-left-color:white;
top:300px;
border-top-color:grey;
border-style:solid;
width: 560px;
left: 390px
}
```

Okay, now moving onto the HTML5 source:

```
    <a id="bottom"></a></div>
<!--Begin page -->

<div id="right">
          <p>FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFff</p>
</div>
```

Okay, now I apologise If this question seems stupid to you, just to backup everything I've explained I've provided a Image of the problem I'm fancing for you to get a better understanding.

[image]

Comment: CSS styles on a div is not an image. Please rewrite your question, to understand what your problem really is, as half of your CSS is not used in the HTML you provided, and the screenshot is just a text over a couple of bordered divs.

Comment: Hey - please understand I'm new to this type of coding language area. I'll edit this to make it more understandable. This will be closed as this has been answered and fixed the problem.

Comment: Your questions must show a research effort. I understand that you are new, but try to search for answers first, since all you were really looking for was a CSS property to wrap your text inside your div.

Comment: Okay thanks - I'll take that into consideration into the future.

Comment: Don't be intimidated to ask questions. Just make sure that your next question won't include a 113 character value into your code, just to show that you have a big text, and try your best to find an answer yourself, so that you can improve your searching skills.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration, It's very helpful. I like to provide big chunks of information to give users more in-depth detail about the 'issue' I'm having.

Comment: Sure. Although (e.g.) posting a 500-line HTML would definitely include the error, it is recommended that you only include the parts that you think cause the problem, and try to summarize your code, instead of pasting stuff.

Comment: Okay - thanks. Your help has gigven me a stronger look too my questions into the future. I do also hope you can help me in the future question of mine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38012/discussion-between-shaun-and-mavrosxristoforos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `word-wrap: break-word;`, this will force the non spaced string to wrap inside an element with a fixed width.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vySPg/)

Comment: You're awesome dude! Thanks for your help and reply; It worked perfectly. It took me awhile to ask this question as simple - anyway thanks again.

Comment: @ShaunS you welcome :) and I guess you are a new user so always accept correct answers whenever you ask a question by clicking on a tick besides my answer :) though you can do that after 15 mins..

Comment: Yeah - I will, and yes I am Indeed. I hope I don't cause problems to people because I am new.

Comment: @ShaunS no it won't :) and don't make your question `[solved]`, selecting my answer as correct will automatically highlight the question answer icon as green

Comment: Okay - and yeah. It's hard trying to talk to people privately.

Comment: @ShaunS you can do that too, we have chat rooms, but you need to earn some reuptation inorder to gain those [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37926/discussion-between-shaun-s-and-mr-alien)